# LSTM with auxiliary data achieves abismal results

Tags: keras, time-series, lstm

I have a fairly simple LSTM models that achieves ok results.
[image]

I wanted to add auxiliary data as appeared in the [keras docs](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models). I added only one binary variable. I expected this model to be at least as good, assuming that if it has no information its weights will go to zero. In reality, the model fails and just predicts zeros for my entire test set.
The second model:
[image]
More specifically, I'm predicting a time series of human-behaviour, and my binary feature tags whether the time point is in a weekend. I'd expect it capture some of the weekend (black background) reduction, and if not, at least not to ruin the model completely.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding a binary variable that is always $1$ or always $0$? If that gives you different results than the model without the binary variable, then you have a bug somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why this new information ***has*** to be a part of your model? There's no rule that says that all data must be fed into your model. Maybe you have just found a feature that shouldn't be included in your predictive phases? And if so, that's perfectly fine, there is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: It doesn't have to, but it makes sense it will, for example by looking at the chart of my training data. I would have accepted if the model hadn't had picked on its importance, but it seems weird that this feature will destroy the model letting predict only zeros.

Comment: @DeanLa It sounds like you're exercising a bit of "researcher bias". Let the data speak to you, not the other way around. You tried it, you got your answer, now you have to be accepting of the answer.

Comment: (Updated the question) I see your point, and I would accepted a lesser model, or the feature to have 0 importance, but the fact that it just predicts zeros seems very weird to me, and makes me believe I'm doing something wrong.